# Xcode *Apple Mach-0 Error

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, mach

Got this error and I'm not sure what's the problem I haven't touched this project in a few weeks, any help is appreciated...

check here for the images
http://s24.postimg.org/nmsnnsxol/Screen_Shot_2014_04_03_at_21_50_32.png
http://s21.postimg.org/jmfzvludj/Screen_Shot_2014_04_03_at_21_50_55.png

Comment: Have you moved your project folders around?

Comment: No not that I can think of, haven't touched the project in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Your library search paths are not proper and that is why the warnings are there `Directory not Found`.
Since it cant find the directory the compilation fails as the classes are not available.

Go to **Build Settings - Library Paths** and make sure your paths are proper based on your project directory.
There should not be jumbled \ strings in it.